# Mysql is not starting using xampp. When I try to view my site on localhost

Tags: mysql, wordpress, logging, xampp

Mysql is not working when I try to view my site on localhost. I keep getting 'Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.' The Mysql log says:

```
2015-05-06 19:39:13 5268 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-05-06 19:39:14 1a88 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1665244 and 1665244 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 71253920 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-05-06 19:39:14 5268 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-05-06 19:39:20 5268 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace budsite/wp_terms uses space ID: 8 at filepath: .\budsite\wp_terms.ibd. Cannot open tablespace phpmyadmin/pma_navigationhiding which uses space ID: 8 at filepath: .\phpmyadmin\pma_navigationhiding.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\phpmyadmin\pma_navigationhiding.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
```

Could someone provide some basic guidance how I can get this working? It would be very appreciated! Xampp works with other sites just not this one. I am working on a wordpress site.

Comment: What OS is your MySQL server running on, how did you install it?

Comment: @Anticom I am using xampp. . I have followed the instructions from here to install xampp http://www.wikihow.com/Install-XAMPP-for-Windows .  The above is xampp